# How to use Google Identity Toolkit to connect to Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, credentials, google-identity-toolkit, api-authorization

I want to use [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/) to sign up and authenticate my users. In another part of my app, I want to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to allow users to choose media files to link with their profile.

Will setting up GITKit make it easier to use the Drive API? Can I share credentials (i.e. API key) between the two services? Are they totally separate? I'm pretty confused so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If its the API key it should work.   However it depends upon the type of application.  IOS and Android like to have their own credentials but most of the time they support credentials created differently in the same project.   Its tricky.  What types of applications do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please consider to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which is the new version of Google Identity Toolkit.

In both Firebase Authentication SDK and Google Identity Toolkit SDK, your app can specify the Google Drive scope when initializing the Google provider. In this way, once the end users sign into your app with Google, your app can get the Google oauth2 access token that has the permission for the Google Drive scope. Your app can call Google Driver API with that access token, without prompting the user.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Firebase Authentication stuff. I had seen a warning about it on the GITKit webpage but I figured I could just ignore it. I guess I can't.